# reinstall grub after installing second linux distro

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I run Ubuntu (more precisely Mint21.3), Windows and one more linux distro on an old Sony Vaio laptop (3rd generation i3 processor). It has only one disk formatted with GPT and uses UEFI.
I I've installed Debian to try it out (as a thirs OS) and it's become the defaul grub entry. Now I'd like to reinstall grub from my everyday Ubuntu to give it back control over the boot process.
As suggested on the Community Help Wiki page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) I've used:
`$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and
`$ sudo update-grub`
they didn't report any issue, but when I reboot I still see the Debian booting option page.
What am I missing?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: BIOS or UEFI install? What brand/model system? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: The commands you executed in your question text were executed from your installed Ubuntu system?  and *sda* is the correct drive?

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I can still boot into the OS, only it's not the first option and the OSes selection page says Debian. The computer has only one disk, sda

Comment: @oldfred Sorry if I didn't include more information: UEFI install on an old Sony Vaio (3rd generation processor). Here the summary report from boot-repair http://sprunge.us/DBnOdv Thanks a lot

Comment: You show Mint & Debian. While Mint uses Ubuntu, it is not an official flavor and not supported here. But,Use Boot-Repair's advance mode and reinstall grub for the install you want to keep. or boot into install & reinstall grub.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks, sorry if I'm posting in the wrong place. Can I run the repair from the running OS or should I create a bootable USB with it?

Comment: You should always have bootable flash drives or external SSDs with current version you have installed to make repairs. You then can easily add repair tools like Boot-Repair with ppa or use other commands like chroot to make repairs. If you can boot into preferred install, just reinstall grub from there.

Comment: @oldfred It worked! I used a live USB to run boot-repair and now grub is back with Mint as first option, great. (the process did return an error: Error: NVram is locked (Linuxmint not found in efibootmgr)  http://sprunge.us/FjaIFH  but it worked in any case). Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you check you bios (UEFI) settings, make sure the right device is set as the highest boot prioity.

Alternatively, in /etc/grub - add

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
```

Then run update-grub.  This will add both installations to the grub boot menu.

Also will set the last operating system you booted to be the default.

I can also highly recomend rEFInd as a boot manager.